# Find all right inverses of matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I'm given the matrix A where it's first row is $(2, -1, 3)$ and second row is $(1, 2, 1)$ and I'm told to find all the right inverses of it. First I tried doing A times a 3x2 vector B (just a vector with inputs $a, b, c, d, e, f$) and multiplying that out to result in the identity matrix. This resulted in my matrix -> first row+ $(2a-c+3e, 2b-d+3f)$ and
second row= (a+2c+e, b+2d+f) where this is all equal to the identity matrix. I tried doing systems of equations but that doesn't really tell me anything except for what $a,b,...e,f$ are in terms of each other, which is a bit useless. What should I be doing?

Comment: You are doing the right thing.  You have found a system of four linear equations in six unknowns.  This will have infinitely many solutions, and your task is to express all of them, e.g. find a basis for the solution space.

Answer (score 2):

You want to solve the system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} \\
x_{31} & x_{32}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This can be written as two linear systems:
$$
\begin{cases}
2x_{11}-x_{21}+3x_{31}=1\\
x_{11}+2x_{21}+x_{31}=0
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
2x_{12}-x_{22}+3x_{32}=0\\
x_{12}+2x_{22}+x_{32}=1
\end{cases}
$$
Can you find all solutions of those systems?

Comment: yeah I got it in the end, was having issues solving the solutions of it